# How to filter list according to $query entered?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I list some contacts. and want to filter md-list according to entered value $query.

```
  <md-contact-chips
                ng-model="ctrl.contacts"
                md-contacts="ctrl.delayedQuerySearch($query)"
                md-contact-name="name"
                md-contact-image="image"
                md-contact-email="email"
                md-require-match="true"
                md-highlight-flags="i"
                filter-selected="ctrl.filterSelected"
                placeholder="To">
        </md-contact-chips>

        <md-list class="memberList">
            <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">Contacts</md-subheader>

                <md-list-item class="md-2-line contact-item" ng-repeat="(index, contact) in ctrl.allContacts | filter: $query"  <!--need set filter according to enrered value-->
                              ng-if="ctrl.contacts.indexOf(contact) < 0">

                    <img class="md-avatar"
                         ng-src="assets/images/avatars/avatar-1.png"
                         src="assets/images/avatars/avatar-1.png">
                    <div class="md-list-item-text compact">
                        <h3>{{contact.name}}</h3>
                        <p>{{contact.email}}</p>
                    </div>
                </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
```

will be glad for help.thanks.

Comment: Where is `$query` set and what is it? A string? Is `ctrl.allContacts` an object?

Comment: I used code form here https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips  .ctrl.allContacts = array of objects. I don't know where $query takes from.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $query is something that is injected inside your controller.
In order to use it in the view you need to bind it to the $scope of the controller.

inside your controller please add the following line assusing $query is of type string. (ie. Value or constant)

```
$scope.query = $query;
```

My feeling is that $query is actually a service of some sort. if that is the case it will have some sort of access function to get the query such as getQuery(), assuming that is the case plese add the following code to inside your controller.

```
$scope.query = $query.getQuery();
$scope.$watch(function() {
            return $query.getQuery();
        }, function(query){
            $scope.query = query;
        });
```

and then last but not least change your html to

```
filter: query
```

please note the question is somewhat broad as it does not explain what $query is.. i hope this helps.. cheers

Comment: Thanks. I also think it is a kind of service. injected $query into controller. and did like you explained, but received:
"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $queryProvider <- $query "

Answer (score 0):

"query" is a custom action on an AngularJS [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).  It's available for use [OOTB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box_(feature)) - you don't need to create an special code to register or use it.

There's a good example in the AngularJS tutorial:

> https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05
>
> app/phone-list/phone-list.template.html:
>
> ```
> <div class="container-fluid">
>   <div class="row">
>     <div class="col-md-2">
>       <!--Sidebar content-->
>
>       Search: <input ng-model="$ctrl.query" />
>
>     </div>
>     <div class="col-md-10">
>       <!--Body content-->
>
>       <ul class="phones">
>         <li ng-repeat="phone in $ctrl.phones | filter:$ctrl.query">
>           <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
>           <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
>         </li>
>       </ul>
>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```